# Slackline vendors/ brick and mortar stores in MD

Tags: united-states, slacklining

What are some slackline vendors or brick and mortar stores in the state of Maryland with people who actually know how to slackline?

I agree that some vendors of slacklines from Amazon may be selling me stuff I don't actually understand and as a newbie to slacklining I want to be able to see what I'm buying in person and prevent returning something.

Comment: It has a lot of cross over with rock climbers... You may have luck going to an REI or any specialist climbing store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try one or both of the following:

- **REI**. At least one employee in the store should have some knowledge. And you can always return within a year if there is a problem with no questions asked. They sell Gibbon slacklines for about $100.
- **Climbing Gym**. If your local climbing gym has a slackline setup (which at least one should), then try asking some of the employees. Most gyms with a slackline setup have a few employees who are very into slacklining, and would be happy to answer a question or two. Maybe even consider getting a daypass and climbing/slacklining for the day if you aren't a member to say thanks (and some others in the gym will then probably give you some slacklining pointers as an added bonus).